# Send data ajax php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Trying to send a variable with ajax to php.

The js:

```
var test1 = "test"
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getid.php",
    data:  {test1 : test1},
    success: function() {
         console.log("message sent!");
    }
});
```

"message sent!" comes up in the console

The php:

```
<?php 
$test1 = $_POST['test1'];
echo $test1; 
?>
```

Error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: test1...
```

I don't really see what i have done wrong here... Any ideas?

UPDATE* when doing `

```
$.ajax({    
        type : "POST",
        url : "getid.php",
        data:  {"test1" : test1},
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log("message sent!");
            console.log(msg);
        }
});
```

This logs "test"

Still getting the same error in the php though..

Comment: No, because then it'd throw an error looking for a constant. It's `$_POST['test1']`.

Comment: @AliBZ nope. please don't advice that.

Comment: For your updated: you need to add `data` as argument to success function.

Comment: i did add it to the success function

Comment: @Koiski add `success: function(**data**) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter you jQuery code:

```
var test1 = "test"
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "getid.php",
    data:  {"test1" : test1}, // this is the row that was causing the problem
    success: function(msg) {
         console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

You had to put `test1` in quotes because it was a defined variable containing "test" which resulted in data being `{"test":"test"}`

Comment: Object keys do not require quotes

Comment: You are right however `test1` is a variable containing `test` which changes the key

Comment: In both cases it will still be "test1": `a = "1"; -> "1"; b = {a: 2}; -> Object {a: 2}; b = {"a": 2}; -> Object {a: 2};`

Comment: @Koiski I've updated the success function, copy paste it to your code and tell me what this logs

Comment: then it works :). "test" is the value you'd expect it to show.

Comment: Yeah but i am still getting the same error when going to: mypage/getid.php or doing this: $.get("getid.php", function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); })

Comment: YES because you have to post the data for it to exist! when you type the address in your browser you don't have `$_POST['test1']`..but when you do the `.ajax()` call you add `data`. to assign a default value you can use `$test1 = isset($_POST['test1']) ? $_POST['test1'] : 'default value';` in your php file

Comment: So how do i get $test1 to echo back "test". the variable from the ajax request??

Comment: When you use `.ajax({type:"post",data:{"test1":"test"}})` you are creating the PHP `$_POST['test1']`. if you don't send data this will not exist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33042/discussion-between-koiski-and-yotam-omer)

Answer (score 0):

Its becouse the response is given to the callback functions as arguments. try somthing like this

```
var test1 = "test"
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getid.php",
    data:  {"test1" : test1},
    success: function(data) { // data argument here
         console.log("message sent!");
         console.log("data:",data); // log it out here 
    }
});
```

Comment: it logs "message sent" "test" but i still get the same error when looking at the php. $.get("getid.php", function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });